How to remove automatically added empty line after environment
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage
[
    top=20mm,
    bottom=20mm,
    left=30mm,
    right=10mm,
    nohead,
    nomarginpar,
    showframe,
]
{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    Kvak
    
    \vfill
    Kvak
    
    \vfill
    Kvak
\end{center}
\end{document}

From output, I see that there is empty line appeared after last Kvak. If I remove center, it won't be there.

If you don't want extra vertical space, use \centering instead of the center environment

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I want to use environment. Is there a way to remove it?

Why do you want an environment?

@DavidCarlisle Could you help, please?

Can you please explain why you want an environment?

It's syntax more elegant, with {} there will be problems with formatter and I need to put empty line before }, or it won't center the last paragraph. This newline will look strange to usual users, who don't know about this peculiarity.

If it is just aesthetic, define a new environment: \newenvironment{foo}{\centering}{\par}

I don't want this behaviour for any environment. Please, help, I'm tired of writing this.
